# Problema al instalar NPM de un Proyecto

Tags: nodejs, deployment

Tengo un problema al subir mi proyecto de node.js a un servidor utilizando Plesk.

A la hora de instalar las dependencias en el servidor despues de subir los archivos, me sale el siquiente error:

No tengo ni idea de lo que trata, pone que es de bcrypt pero lo he intentado solucionar y nada, alguno sabe a lo que se debe ?

```
npm WARN read-shrinkwrap This version of npm is compatible with lockfileVersion@1, but package-lock.json was generated for lockfileVersion@2. I'll try to do my best with it!
npm WARN lifecycle npm is using /opt/plesk/node/12/bin/node but there is no node binary in the current PATH. Use the  ``--scripts-prepend-node-path` ` option to include the path for the node binary npm was executed with.
/usr/bin/env: ‘node’: No such file or directory
npm WARN back@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! bcrypt@5.0.1 install: ``node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build``
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@5.0.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! /var/www/vhosts/growthroadpruebas.es/.npm/_logs/2021-06-11T08_12_35_916Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Tuve el mismo problema y la solución fue copiar `node_modules` completa, obviamente no está bien.  El problema en verdad es con `gyp` , se supone que la solución es usar `bcryptjs`, que es "autónoma",  lo que sucede es que seguramente tu no estés usando `bcrypt` sino otra dependencia. El problema entiendo es que `bcrypt`/`gyp`  necesita dependencias del SO, quizá esto te resulte de ayuda https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/wiki/Installation-Instructions